# Problems during share files using samba protocol in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, permissions, nautilus, samba

I want to share files among 2 devices. Let's say Computer A (running Ubuntu 20.04) and Computer B (running Kubuntu 20.04) connected to the same wireless network. I want A to access the public folder of B and vice versa. After installing samba and configuring share properties and allowing guest access, I can access the public folders of a machine with another machine flawlessly, but anonymously. Quite happy with that.

Now I have 2 problems:

#### 1. Changing permissions for enclosed files

---

When I want to put a folder containing files or sub-folders from B to the public folder of A, then I get an error about the lack of permission. Then I tried to change the permission of the folder of A by right click **Properties > Permissions > Change permissions for enclosed files**

[image: Public Properties dialog]

Can't edit the permissions from here even using nautilus as root user.

#### 2. Accessing the public folders as a registered user

---

I want to set public folders so the only can be accessed using username and password, instead of guest access. I tried `sudo smbpasswd -a <USER_NAME>`, however it returned an error of failure to add entry. Then after digging in Internet I found out that `<USER_NAME>` must be a system user.

The thing is that I believe samba v4 doesn't need a system user. I have v4.11.6. So how do I add a samba user only?

Answer (score 0):

OK, how far do you want me to go into showing you how to set up a Samba AD DC ? ;-)

You are probably running Samba as a standalone server, with 'map to guest = bad user' in [global] and 'guest ok = yes' set in the share (note: 'public' is a synonym for 'guest ok'), so without Samba users, all your users become the 'guest' user (usually 'nobody').

If you want Samba users on a standalone server, then there must be a corresponding Linux user, sorry, but that is just the way it is.

Comment: Actually your answer sounds jargon to me. Can you elaborate? M new to Linux thingy.

Comment: It's more structured in Linux since you need to add a preexisting local server user to the samba password database ( smbpasswd -a ) but the concept is identical to Windows. In order to access a Windows share as "bob" "bob" must exist on the Windows machine. BTW, you don't have to create a new user. You can add yourself via smbpasswd - just give yourself a samba password that is different from your local logon password if the client user is not you.